# Submenu for navbar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, web, navbar

I have my website made in flutter and I need to create a submenu for my navbar, when you click on the NavbarItem where the user's name is (users.firstName).
Below I share with you the code.

```
class NavBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavBar({Key? key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final user = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context).user!;
    final token = LocalStorage.prefs.getString('token');
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 75,
      decoration: buildBoxDecoration(),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          if (size.width <= 779) ...[
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                SideMenuProvider.openMenu();
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.menu_outlined),
            ),
            const Spacer(),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 2),
              child: Container(
                width: 250,
                child: const AutoSizeText(
                  'SISTEMA WEB DE COSTOS Y RENTABILIDAD DEL PROCESO DEL CULTIVO DEL BANANO',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                  maxLines: 5, // Número máximo de líneas permitidas
                  minFontSize: 10, // Tamaño de fuente mínimo
                  maxFontSize: 30, // Tamaño de fuente máximo
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, // Opción de desbordamiento
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
          if (size.width >= 779) ...[
            const SizedBox(
              width: 5,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 2),
              child: Container(
                width: 250,
                child: const AutoSizeText(
                  'SISTEMA WEB DE COSTOS Y RENTABILIDAD DEL PROCESO DEL CULTIVO DEL BANANO',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                  maxLines: 5, // Número máximo de líneas permitidas
                  minFontSize: 10, // Tamaño de fuente mínimo
                  maxFontSize: 30, // Tamaño de fuente máximo
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, // Opción de desbordamiento
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const Spacer(),
            NavbarItem(
                text: 'Inicio',
                icon: Icons.home_sharp,
                onPressed: () {
                  NavigationService.replaceTo(Flurorouter.dashboardRoute);
                }),
            /*NavbarItem(
                text: 'Opciones de perfil',
                icon: Icons.settings,
                onPressed: () {}),*/
            NavbarItem(
                text: 'Datos',
                icon: Icons.people,
                onPressed: () {
                  NavigationService.replaceTo('/dashboard/info/$token');
                },
                isActive: false),
            NavbarItem(
                text: 'Password',
                icon: Icons.people,
                onPressed: () {
                  NavigationService.replaceTo(Flurorouter.changePassRoute);
                },
                isActive: false),
            NavbarItem(
                text: user.firstName,
                icon: Icons.people,
                onPressed: () {
                  //crearMenu(context);
                },
                isActive: false),
            NavbarItem(
              text: 'Salir',
              icon: Icons.exit_to_app_outlined,
              onPressed: () {
                Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false).logout();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  BoxDecoration buildBoxDecoration() => const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.centerLeft, // Comienza desde la izquierda
            end: Alignment.centerRight, // Termina en la derecha
            colors: [
              Color(0xFF679C64), // Color de inicio
              Color(0xFFADCFAB), // Color de finalización
            ],
          ),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              blurRadius: 5,
              color: Colors.black12,
            )
          ]);
```

The NavbarItem consists of:

```
class NavbarItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  final IconData icon;
  final bool isActive;
  final Function onPressed;

  const NavbarItem({
    required this.text,
    required this.icon,
    this.isActive = false,
    required this.onPressed,
  });

  @override
  State<NavbarItem> createState() => _NavbarItemState();
}

class _NavbarItemState extends State<NavbarItem> {
  bool isHover = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: widget.isActive ? null : () => widget.onPressed(),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
          child: MouseRegion(
            onEnter: (_) => setState(() {
              isHover = true;
            }),
            onExit: (_) => setState(() {
              isHover = false;
            }),
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Icon(widget.icon),
                Text(
                  widget.text,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    decoration: isHover
                        ? TextDecoration.underline
                        : TextDecoration.none,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How can I do it?

I need to change that NavbarItem for some widget that allows me to achieve to show more options to get the behavior of a submenu.
I would also like to know if those submenu options can be customized and be like the following widget, which is an AnimatedContainer that I use for the side menu, I like the way it works and I would like to integrate that widget as a custom option:

```
class SidebarItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  final Function onPressed;
  final bool isActive;
  final IconData icon;

  const SidebarItem({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
    required this.onPressed,
    this.isActive = false,
    required this.icon,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SidebarItem> createState() => _SidebarItemState();
}

class _SidebarItemState extends State<SidebarItem> {
  bool isHover = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color backgroundColor = isHover
        ? const Color(0xFF184D26)
        : widget.isActive
            ? const Color(0xFF184D26)
            : Colors.transparent;
    return AnimatedContainer(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
        color: backgroundColor,
        child: Material(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: InkWell(
              onTap: widget.isActive ? null : () => widget.onPressed(),
              child: Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 10),
                child: MouseRegion(
                  onEnter: (_) => setState(() {
                    isHover = true;
                  }),
                  onExit: (_) => setState(() {
                    isHover = false;
                  }),
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Icon(widget.icon),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 5,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        widget.text,
                        /*style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                          fontSize: 14,
                          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8),
                        ),*/
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )),
        ));
  }
}
```

I want to achieve something like this: I need to show two options 'change password' and 'update information'.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szGPH.jpg)

**MRE**

Ok this is my main:

```
return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  title: 'BananoProject',
  initialRoute: '/',
  onGenerateRoute: Flurorouter.router.generator,
  navigatorKey: NavigationService.navigatorKey,
  scaffoldMessengerKey: NotificationsService.messengerKey,
  builder: (_, child) {

    final authProvider = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context);

    if (authProvider.authStatus == AuthStatus.checking){
      return SplashLayout();
    }

    if(authProvider.authStatus == AuthStatus.authenticated){
      return DashboardLayout(child: child!);
```

Once logged in, the user can access the DashboardLayout, which is the main window of the application.

```
class DashboardLayout extends StatefulWidget {
 final Widget child;

 const DashboardLayout({ required this.child});

 @override
 State<DashboardLayout> createState() => _DashboardLayoutState();
}
class _DashboardLayoutState extends State<DashboardLayout>
with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
@override
void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
super.initState();

SideMenuProvider.menuController = AnimationController(
    vsync: this, duration: const Duration(microseconds: 300));
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

return Scaffold(
    body: Container(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: AssetImage('assets/moduls_background.jpeg'),
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    ),
  ),
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                const NavBar( ),

                //navbar
                Expanded(child: widget.child),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
));
}
}
```

As you can see the navbar is inside the DashboardLayout and only the logged in user can see it.
When implementing your shared code I got the mentioned error, here I share the navbar:

```
enum Options { changePassword, logout }

void onSelected(item) {
  switch (item) {
  case Options.changePassword:
   debugPrint('Change Password pressed');
  break;
  case Options.logout:
   debugPrint('Change Password pressed');
  break;
}
}

class NavBar extends StatelessWidget {
const NavBar({Key? key});

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final navbarItem = AbsorbPointer(
  child: NavbarItem(
    text: 'Salir',
    icon: Icons.exit_to_app_outlined,
    onPressed: () {
      print('Hola');
    },
  ),
);

List<PopupMenuEntry<Options>> itemBuilder(context) => [
      const PopupMenuItem(
        value: Options.changePassword,
        child: Text('Change Password'),
      ),
      const PopupMenuItem(
        value: Options.logout,
        child: Text('Logout'),
      ),
    ];

final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
final user = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context).user!;
final token = LocalStorage.prefs.getString('token');

return Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    width: double.infinity,
    height: 75,
    decoration: buildBoxDecoration(),
    child: Row(
      children: [
        if (size.width <= 779) ...[
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              SideMenuProvider.openMenu();
            },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.menu_outlined),
          ),
          const Spacer(),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 2),
            child: Container(
              width: 250,
              child: const AutoSizeText(
                'SISTEMA WEB DE COSTOS Y RENTABILIDAD DEL PROCESO DEL CULTIVO DEL BANANO',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
                maxLines: 5, // Número máximo de líneas permitidas
                minFontSize: 10, // Tamaño de fuente mínimo
                maxFontSize: 30, // Tamaño de fuente máximo
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, // Opción de desbordamiento
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
        if (size.width >= 779) ...[
          const SizedBox(
            width: 5,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 2),
            child: Container(
              width: 250,
              child: const AutoSizeText(
                'SISTEMA WEB DE COSTOS Y RENTABILIDAD DEL PROCESO DEL CULTIVO DEL BANANO',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
                maxLines: 5, // Número máximo de líneas permitidas
                minFontSize: 10, // Tamaño de fuente mínimo
                maxFontSize: 30, // Tamaño de fuente máximo
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, // Opción de desbordamiento
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const Spacer(),
          NavbarItem(
              text: 'Inicio',
              icon: Icons.home_sharp,
              onPressed: () {
                NavigationService.replaceTo(Flurorouter.dashboardRoute);
              }),
          /*NavbarItem(
            text: 'Opciones de perfil',
            icon: Icons.settings,
            onPressed: () {}),*/
          NavbarItem(
              text: 'Datos',
              icon: Icons.people,
              onPressed: () {
                NavigationService.replaceTo('/dashboard/info/$token');
              },
              isActive: false),
          NavbarItem(
              text: 'Password',
              icon: Icons.people,
              onPressed: () {
                NavigationService.replaceTo(Flurorouter.changePassRoute);
              },
              isActive: false),
          NavbarItem(
              text: user.firstName,
              icon: Icons.people,
              onPressed: () {
                //crearMenu(context);
              },
              isActive: false),
          Container(
              width: 50,
              child: Overlay(
                initialEntries: [
                  OverlayEntry(builder: (context) {
                    return PopupMenuButton(
                      onSelected: onSelected,
                      itemBuilder: itemBuilder,
                      child: navbarItem,
                    );
                  })
                ],
              )),
          NavbarItem(
            text: 'Salir',
            icon: Icons.exit_to_app_outlined,
            onPressed: () {
              Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context, listen: false).logout();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ],
    ),
  );
});
}

BoxDecoration buildBoxDecoration() => const BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.centerLeft, // Comienza desde la izquierda
          end: Alignment.centerRight, // Termina en la derecha
          colors: [
            Color(0xFF679C64), // Color de inicio
            Color(0xFFADCFAB), // Color de finalización
          ],
        ),
        boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(
          blurRadius: 5,
          color: Colors.black12,
        )
      ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Try `PopupMenuButton`

Final appearance may vary  depending on theme.

[image: PopupMenuButton hover][image: PopupMenuButton click]

Use the `child` parameter for what to display as a button, the `onSelected` for what to do with the value to be provided at `PopupMenuItem` and the `itemBuilder` to build the items.

1. Declare a list of options or an enum in this case to be more descriptive`

```dart
enum Options { changePassword, logout }
```

2. The child used as the button, else it may show a default 3 dots icon. This is the `NavbarItem` wrapped with `AbsorbPointer` to override its `onPressed` function.

```dart
final navbarItem = AbsorbPointer(
  child: NavbarItem(
    text: 'Salir',
    icon: Icons.exit_to_app_outlined,
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
);
```

3. onSelected

```dart
void onSelected(item) {
  switch (item) {
    case Options.changePassword:
      debugPrint('Change Password pressed');
      break;
    case Options.logout:
      debugPrint('Change Password pressed');
      break;
  }
}
```

4. itemBuilder

```dart
List<PopupMenuEntry<Options>> itemBuilder(context) => [
      const PopupMenuItem(
        value: Options.changePassword,
        child: Text('Change Password'),
      ),
      const PopupMenuItem(
        value: Options.logout,
        child: Text('Logout'),
      ),
    ];
```

5. Pace it where you want to use it

```dart
PopupMenuButton(
  onSelected: onSelected,
  itemBuilder: itemBuilder,
  child: navbarItem,
),
```

---

## MRE

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const App());
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

enum Options { changePassword, logout }

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Center(
        child: PopupMenuButton(
          onSelected: onSelected,
          itemBuilder: itemBuilder,
          child: navbarItem,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

final navbarItem = AbsorbPointer(
  child: NavbarItem(
    text: 'Salir',
    icon: Icons.exit_to_app_outlined,
    onPressed: () {},
  ),
);
void onSelected(item) {
  switch (item) {
    case Options.changePassword:
      debugPrint('Change Password pressed');
      break;
    case Options.logout:
      debugPrint('Change Password pressed');
      break;
  }
}

List<PopupMenuEntry<Options>> itemBuilder(context) => [
      const PopupMenuItem(
        value: Options.changePassword,
        child: Text('Change Password'),
      ),
      const PopupMenuItem(
        value: Options.logout,
        child: Text('Logout'),
      ),
    ];

class NavbarItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  final IconData icon;
  final bool isActive;
  final Function onPressed;

  const NavbarItem({
    super.key,
    required this.text,
    required this.icon,
    this.isActive = false,
    required this.onPressed,
  });

  @override
  State<NavbarItem> createState() => _NavbarItemState();
}

class _NavbarItemState extends State<NavbarItem> {
  bool isHover = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: widget.isActive ? null : () => widget.onPressed(),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
        child: MouseRegion(
          onEnter: (_) => setState(() {
            isHover = true;
          }),
          onExit: (_) => setState(() {
            isHover = false;
          }),
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Icon(widget.icon),
              Text(
                widget.text,
                style: TextStyle(
                  decoration:
                      isHover ? TextDecoration.underline : TextDecoration.none,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I got this error:
No overlay wdiget found.
Tooltip widgets rquire an Overlay widget ancestor within the clossest LookupBoundary.
An overlay lets widgets float on top of other widget children.
To introduce an Overlay widget, you can wither directly include one, or use a widget that contains an Overlay itself..

Comment: Hard to tell without code. Can you post an MRE? I update the question with one.

Comment: I have already updated the question

Comment: Seems like the issue is at [builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/builder.html) property of `MaterialApp`. See also [MenuAnchor](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MenuAnchor-class.html)

Comment: It works, tahnks!!